# Replacing Dataframe Objects - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some support with something simple but that is perplexing me a bit. I am trying to replace some values from an excel I am working with.

My values are from 1 to 5, but I'll like to replace them to Very Unsatisfied, Unsatisfied and so on. I run my code and it gives me no errors but for some reason it is not being replaced.

For some context, data is the name of my dataframe and CSAT is the column where te numerical values are. Nothing too crazy.

`data["CSAT"].replace(to_replace=['5' , '4' , '3' , '2' , '1'] , value=['Very Satisfied' , 'Satisfied', 'Neutral', 'Unsatisfied' , 'Very Unsatisfied'])`

I also tried

`data["CSAT"].replace(['5' , '4' , '3' , '2' , '1'] , ['Very Satisfied' , 'Satisfied', 'Neutral', 'Unsatisfied' , 'Very Unsatisfied'])`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you tried assigning back? `.replace` isn't in-place; need `df[col] = df[col].replace(...)`

Comment: I tried data["CSAT"] = data["CSAT"].replace(to_replace=['5' , '4' , '3' , '2' , '1'],value=['Very Satisfied' , 'Satisfied', 'Neutral', 'Unsatisfied' , 'Very Unsatisfied']) .. But there is still the same, no change.

Comment: that means your values are not what you think they are... like there's no literally '5' in them. can you check that? `print(df[col].unique().tolist())` should give a list of uniques

Comment: I got this when I printed it [4, 5, 2, 1, 3] . So, should I replace in that order and add what I want accordingly?

Comment: It is fixed, I added the numbers without the '' I though that adding the numbers without the '' would replace the index instead. Any reason that did not happen?

Comment: *I got this when I printed it [4, 5, 2, 1, 3]*: so they are numbers, not strings; hence the replacement failing because it had quotes like '5' etc.

Comment: *I though that adding the numbers without the '' would replace the index instead.* Not sure what you mean; `s.replace` works only on the *values* of the Series `s` you're using it on, not the index of it.